# Extension operator $P: W^{k, p}(\Omega) \to W^{k, p}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, sobolev-spaces

In my functional analysis course, we are studying the *extension operator* and there is something I really don't understand. Let me explain my problem for the case $\Omega = \mathbb R^n_+ = \{x \in \mathbb R^n~|~x_n > 0\}$ and $k = 1$.

For such an open set, there is a linear continuous operator $P: W^{1, p}(\mathbb R^n_+) \to W^{1, p}(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $(Pu)|_{\mathbb R^n_+} = u$. To construct such an operator, we use the approximation of $W^{1, p}(\mathbb R^n_+)$ by $C^\infty (\overline{\mathbb R^n_+})\cap W^{1, p}(\mathbb R^n_+)$ to define
$$
Pu(x',x_n) = \begin{cases}
u(x', x_n) & \text{if }~ x_n \ge 0,\\
u(x', -x_n) & \text{if }~ x_n < 0,
\end{cases}
$$
Such that $Pu \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb R^n)$ and we can conclude by density. It is the same kind of argument on $\Omega$ smooth and bounded.

My question is the following: why do we need to construct the extension like that ? It seems much more natural to define
$$
Pu(x',x_n) = \begin{cases}
u(x', x_n) & \text{if }~ x_n \ge 0,\\
0 & \text{if }~ x_n < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
What could possibly goes wrong with the extension by zero of functions of $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the jump of the derivative of the function at the boundary!

Indeed, for a function in $L^2(\Omega)$, it is natural to extend by $0$ outside. However, for a function $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, if you extend by $0$ outside $\Omega$, you might have that $u$ is discontinuous at $\partial \Omega$, and therefore nothing ensures you that

$$\nabla u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

However, if $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, you can extend by $0$ without any problem.

Comment: But in the definition of $P$ by reflexion, the derive is also singular on $x_n = 0$. Why is there a problem when we extend by zero and none when extending by reflection ?

Comment: Don't forget that the derivative is defined in a weak sense. The extension by reflexion is exactly perfomed so that the two irregular parts of $\nabla P u$ (written in the weak way) negates each other at the boundary $\{ x_n=0 \}$. To convince you of that, I suggest you to writte and compute, for $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R}^n)$: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} Pu(x',x_n) \nabla \varphi dx' \ dx^n.$$ (Split the integral in two, performs two integration by parts, the two boundary terms should disappear and you'll be left with the definition of $\nabla Pu$ which will be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ !)

Comment: Ok yes I see, thank you!